# Screen Jumps (scrolls) to the top when trying to format text

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I'm creating a page with multiple anchor points (bookmarks) but every time I go to format my text (size change, font color, bold, etc.) it my screen jumps (scrolls) to top the page and I have scroll all the way back down.

Is anyone having this same problem or figured out how to fix it? I'm tried it chrome and IE and get the same result.

I'm working with Sharepoint 2010 at work.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!